# Sound picker / List of system sounds on macOS

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, system-sounds, nssound

Okay. I was looking for a neat way to list system sounds that are played with [NSSound soundNamed: ] - and to me it seemed that API does not have list of available sounds.

I also searched this with google and found some pretty old and partially already deprecated sources. If application should have *a soundpicker* - what would be a best way to get list of system provided sounds?

Comment: **This is not a duplicate.** The other question targets CocoaTouch/iOS and is not asking for a list of system sounds.!

Answer (score 10):

This is my implementation.

NSSound (systemSounds.h):

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface NSSound (systemSounds)

+ (NSArray *) systemSounds;

@end
```

NSSound (systemSounds.m):

```
#import "NSSound (systemSounds).h"

@implementation NSSound (systemSounds)

static NSArray *systemSounds = nil;

+ (NSArray *) systemSounds
{
    if ( !systemSounds )
    {
        NSMutableArray *returnArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSEnumerator *librarySources = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSAllDomainsMask, YES) objectEnumerator];
        NSString *sourcePath;

        while ( sourcePath = [librarySources nextObject] )
        {
            NSEnumerator *soundSource = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath: [sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Sounds"]];
            NSString *soundFile;
            while ( soundFile = [soundSource nextObject] )
                if ( [NSSound soundNamed: [soundFile stringByDeletingPathExtension]] )
                    [returnArr addObject: [soundFile stringByDeletingPathExtension]];           
        }

        systemSounds = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [returnArr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
        [returnArr release];
    }
    return systemSounds;
}

@end
```

Freely usable and available for anyone for any purpose and if you enhance it, please share :)

Comment: Super! Thanks. But now tell me: how to play (one of them)? I mean we have the array with the names, but how (what is the code) to play (say "Glass.aiff")?

Comment: @Gik `[[NSSound soundNamed:@"Glass"] play];`

Comment: Here's a Swift 5.1 version: https://gist.github.com/Iomegan/edd82f1d903cb05f648096ab853340e0