# How to get alarm sound list

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to get all ringtones and select to use same as Clock App in iPhone?

**Edit:: I test on my iPhone 5.**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that **this is not possible**.

There aren't any official API that allows you to do that.

Comment: I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949138/sound-picker-list-of-system-sounds , is this no longer valid?

Comment: The answer you linked is about OS X. Unfortunately, it is not possible to do it on iOS.

Comment: I test this app on my phone